# placemark is green on the map but orange on the navigation bar

Tags: xml, google-maps, maps, kml

I was wondering if you can advise on me or point me into the right direction on the following issue.

In a KML file I have a placemark whose styling tells it to be orange; however it appears as GREEN on the map:

[image]

As you can see in the navigation bar it is orange:

[image]

What is causing this to happen?

Here's a picture of the map:

[image]

**Why is the placemark a different color on the map than the navigation bar?** Please note that, some placemarks work (they are the same color on the map and navigation), whereas, some do not work! **What am I doing wrong?**

Here's my KML header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"><Document>
    <name></name>
    <description></description>
    <Style id="MentalHealthFacilitiesClinic">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>1</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://static.batchgeo.com/images/icons/orange_shadow_Marker.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <hotSpot x=".3" y=".8" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>0</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[ <b>$[name]</b><br />$[address]<br />$[description]]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>


       <Style id="MentalHealthFacilitiesHospital">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>1</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://static.batchgeo.com/images/icons/orange_shadow_Marker.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <hotSpot x=".3" y=".8" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>0</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[ <b>$[name]</b><br />$[address]<br />$[description]]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>


       <Style id="MentalHealthFacilitiesLTC">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>1</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://static.batchgeo.com/images/icons/orange_shadow_Marker.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <hotSpot x=".3" y=".8" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>0</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[ <b>$[name]</b><br />$[address]<br />$[description]]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>


       <Style id="MLCustomer">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>1</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://static.batchgeo.com/images/icons/green_shadow_Marker.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <hotSpot x=".3" y=".8" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>0</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[ <b>$[name]</b><br />$[address]<br />$[description]]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>


       <Style id="PastMLCustomer">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>1</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://static.batchgeo.com/images/icons/yellow_shadow_Marker.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <hotSpot x=".3" y=".8" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>0</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[ <b>$[name]</b><br />$[address]<br />$[description]]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>


       <Style id="SuboxoneTreatment">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>1</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://static.batchgeo.com/images/icons/blue_shadow_Marker.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <hotSpot x=".3" y=".8" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>0</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[ <b>$[name]</b><br />$[address]<br />$[description]]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>


     <Style id="SuboxonePrescribers">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>1</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://static.batchgeo.com/images/icons/paleblue_shadow_Marker.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <hotSpot x=".3" y=".8" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>0</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[ <b>$[name]</b><br />$[address]<br />$[description]]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
```

Comment: You sure you don't have two markers on top of each other?  You didn't provide your complete KML file or a link to it.

Comment: yes i am pretty sure. i zoomed in all the way into it, and saw only one

Comment: If they are directly on top of each other the only real way to tell is the shadow is darker or by looking at the KML file.

Comment: @geocodezip you definitely know your stuff! the shadow does get darker, please hold, im going to see if i have the same coordinates ont he map

Comment: @geocodezip you are exactly right! thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two markers directly on top of each other.  You can tell by the way the shadow is darker or by looking at the KML file.

Comment: because you didn't include enough information in the original post to tell for real.  Can't change the down vote unless you edit the post at this point.

Comment: would you happen to know why on my ipad, if i press anywhere on the map, it adds a placemark? do you know how i can disable this with the kml?

Comment: I don't have an iPad.  But that doesn't have anything to do with the KML (at least it shouldn't), it is the application that is displaying the KML.

Comment: thank you again. that makes sense. can you please point me into the right direction on the style tag. i want the balloon in the google maps kml to be more fancy can you give me any example?